# How to execute SQL query in psycopg2 with iterable and non-iterable parameters

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, iterable

I'm trying perform a DELETE-query in PostgreSQL-database using psycopg2 with two parameters:

```
person_id = 1
```

and

```
role_id_list = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

So in the database, a person with certain id can have specific "roles", which are specified by a list of tuple integers. The reason why the `role_id_list` is a list of tuples rather than list of integers is because this is the return format of another SQL-query I have.

Anyway, I want to delete all occurrences from my `person_roles` table where `perdon_id = 1` and `role_id` is in the list `role_id_list`

Because I have a iterable object as a parameter I checked that I should use the `executemany`-function in psycopg2:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany

So the function takes an iterable as a parameter, but what if I have a non-iterable and iterable parameters as I do in my example?

I tried my luck with the following function:

```
def delete_person_roles(person_id, role_id_list):

        sql = "DELETE FROM person_roles WHERE person_id = %s AND role_id = %s;"
        conn = None
        try:
            # read database configuration
            # connect to the PostgreSQL database
            conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host="localhost",
                database="mydatabase",
                user="myuser",
                password="mypassword")
            # create a new cursor
            cur = conn.cursor()
            # execute the DELETE statement
            cur.executemany(sql, (person_id, role_id_list))
            # commit the changes to the database
            conn.commit()
            # close communication with the database
            cur.close()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
        finally:
            if conn is not None:
                conn.close()
```

and if I now call:

```
delete_person_roles(person_id, role_id_list)
```

I get the message:

```
'int' object does not support indexing
```

**So my question is:** is it possible to pass both iterable and non-iterable parameters in psycopg2 without using `for`-loops? Or should I simply use `for`-loops and make the deletions one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a workaround. By editing the SQL-query in the function in the following way:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM person_roles WHERE person_id = %s AND role_id = ANY(%s);"
```

and then simply using `execute` instead of `executemany` got everything working.

So this function works:

```
def delete_person_roles(person_id, role_id_list):

    sql = "DELETE FROM person_roles WHERE person_id = %s AND role_id = ANY(%s);"
    conn = None
    try:
        # read database configuration
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host="localhost",
            database="mydatabase",
            user="myuser",
            password="mypassword")
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the DELETE statement
        cur.execute(sql, (person_id, role_id_list))
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Comment: For troubleshooting use mogrify() method of cursor (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html).